# Can primefaces call a listener on datatable row edit click?

Tags: java, primefaces

I'd like to know if there's an ajax event I can use for when clicking the edit "pen", but at the point where the row becomes editable, not when it goes and updates the row.

Answer (score 2):

In PF User Guide 5; There is a list of ajax behaviour events for datatable.

Inside this list, there is;

> rowEditInit : When a row switches to edit mode

so I guess it may be suitable for your problem

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit " listener="#{beanName.methodName}" update="partToBeUpdated" />
```